# Haskell - how to change the show to get the right output

Tags: haskell

I have defined these datatypes which I am trying to create and print now.

```
type TNonTerminal = String -- will be creating own ones where [A-Z] won't be enough
type TTerminals = Char
type TSymbols = String -- both terminals and nonterminals

data Rule = Rule
    { leftSide :: TNonTerminal
    , rightSide :: [TSymbols]
    } deriving (Eq)

data RightLinearGrammar = RLG
    { nonterminals :: [TNonTerminal]
    , terminals :: [TTerminals]
    , firstNonterminal :: TNonTerminal
    , rules :: [Rule]
    } deriving (Eq)
```

So I also created those Show instances

```
instance Show Rule where
    show (Rule ls rs) = show ls ++ "->" ++ show rs ++ "\n"

instance Show RightLinearGrammar where
    show (RLG n t fn r) = show n ++ "\n" ++ show t ++ "\n" ++ show fn ++ "\n" ++ show r ++ "\n"
```

And I get this output (for clarification I created the Type RightLinearGrammar and called `putStr $ show rlg`):

```
["A","B"]          -- [TNonTerminal]
"abc"              -- [TTerminals]
"A"                -- TNonTerminal
["A"->["aaB"]      --
,"A"->["ccB"]
,"B"->["bB"]       --  [Rule]
,"B"->["#"]
]                  --
```

How should I change the code to get better output like this one?

```
A,B
a,b,c
A
A->aaB
A->ccB
B->bB
B->#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` is by default going to give you quotes around strings and brackets around lists. If you just go back to concatenating strings and joining lists with commas or newlines, you should get the output you're expecting:

```haskell
import Data.List (intercalate)

instance Show Rule where
    show (Rule ls rs) = ls ++ "->" ++ intercalate "," rs

instance Show RightLinearGrammar where
    show (RLG n t fn r) = intercalate "," n ++ "\n" ++ t ++ "\n" ++ fn ++ "\n" ++ (intercalate "\n" $ map show r) ++ "\n"
```

Comment: That works. Didn't know that such functions like intersperse and concat exist.

Comment: I just updated it to use `intercalate`, which is shorthand for `concat $ intersperse xs xss`

Answer (score 1):

You either need to replace your type synonyms with `newtypes`, and define `show` on them to do what you want, or more likely replace the calls to `show` in your instances with calls to a custom formatter function.

Note: `show` is really not the right function for what you're trying to do, since it usually produces output you could paste back into `ghci` and arguably should be limitted to that use.  You could easily define your own function and use it like this:

```
formatRule :: Rule -> String
formatRule (Rule ls rs) = ls ++ "->" ++ concat (intersperse "," rs) ++ "\n"

formatRightLinearGrammar :: RightLinearGrammar -> String
formatRightLinearGrammar (RLG n t fn r) =
       concat (intersperse "," n) ++ "\n"
    ++ intersperse ',' t ++ "\n"
    ++ fn ++ "\n"
    ++ concat (map formatRule r)
```

Note: this is going to be fairly inefficient for large grammars; you might want to consider re-writing it as

```
formatRule :: Rule -> String -> String
formatRule (Rule ls rs) = (ls++) . ("->"++) . concatDS (intersperse "," rs) . ("\n"++)

formatRightLinearGrammar :: RightLinearGrammar -> String
formatRightLinearGrammar (RLG n t fn r) =
    concatDS (intersperse "," n) $ ("\n"++) $
    (intersperse ',' t ++) $ ("\n"++) $
    (fn++) $ ("\n"++) $
    foldr formatRule "" r

concatDS ss s' = foldr (++) s' ss
```